# MongoDB Complex Record Performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a large collection 300K records of very large and complex records. Aggregation framework seems to struggle when working with nested arrays and objects. If I wanted to set up Views where I have simplified the record, is it better to have many records of very basic data that comprises a single complex record or a single flat record that has hundreds of dynamic field names?

Here is an example

```
var obj = {
    orderID:1,
    items:[
        {
            sku:"abc123",
            price:"$1.21"
        },
        {
            sku:"aaa111",
            price:"$2.21"
        },
        {
            sku:"bbb222",
            price:"$3.21"
        }
    ]
}

var vertical = [ //Each item is a record in the collection
    {
        orderID:1,
        sku:"abc123",
        price:"$1.21"
    },
    {
        orderID:1,
        sku:"aaa111",
        price:"$3.21"
    },
    {
        orderID:1,
        sku:"bbb222",
        price:"$3.21"
    }
];

var flat = { // A single record in the collection
    orderID:1,
    abc123:"$1.21",
    aaa111:"$2.21",
    bbb222:"$3:21"
}
```

In my case, each record includes anywhere from 200-1000 items in the arrays within the record. So think of this scaled up to the extreme.

With vertical, I have well defined fields(indexable) and the records are small. But in my DB it would generate around 50M of these bite sized records.

With flat, I only have to pull a single record and as long as I know the fields I am looking for, it can work. But the fields are dynamic and not indexable.

With the only purpose of this being for reporting use, what is the best way to go?

Comment: The "struggle" will be purely about the items in the array over 500. The "other" struggle will be your actual implementation, which is notably *"missing from your question"*. So you have performance problems with your code, but you aren't showing what you are doing. Seems like the way for people to help you with your problems is show what you are doing. Also all the `"price"` values here are strings, which is pretty bad in every situation I can think of.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks for the response. There is no specific issue except for me seeing a slow down in my reporting queries(of all kind)as the db grows. This lead me to exploring the option of creating a collection that is optimized for aggregating data and reporting use. Please dont get hung up on the data in my example I dont have a `sku` or `price` field in my db at all. It was purely an example. I guess this is more a data structure question than anything.

Comment: Sorry but I completely disagree with your point of view here as **your actual code is the only importance**. To explain that, processing arrays in aggregation is typically done with `$unwind`, but newer releases of MongoDB are consistently working on ways to avoid this. Secondly a choice of "arrays vs records" is like "coke vs pepsi". It **does not matter** what someones opinion is, it's all about "how you use the data". So presumably if you put things in an array, then you did so for a reason. The question is "does the storage pattern match the usage"? That's what is not expressed here.

Comment: I just saw [MongoDB Collection Structure Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36018035/5031275) of which this is basically a **duplicate** of. I would have put an immediate close on this question had I seen that first. At any rate, it probably wasn't the wisest choice to put up a bounty on a question with multiple close votes on it. For much the same reason here, without specific detail you are just asking "coke vs pepsi". I like "coke", but that information should be as useful as any response you will get to such a question.